# Is there any possibility to recover A in "A & B = C" with given B and C?

Tags: c, algorithm, logic, circuit

I would like to ask: with `A`, `B`, and `C` are any binary number. After getting `C = A & B` (`&` is `AND` operator), is there any possibility to recover `A` from `B` and `C`?

I know that the information of `A` will be lost through the operation. Can we form a function like `B <...> C = A`, and how complexity it can be?

For example:

```
A = 0011
B = 1010
C = A & B = 0010
```

The 2nd bit of `C` is `1`, i.e. 2nd bit of `A` and `B` must be `1`. However, the other bits lack information to be recovered.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `C = A & B` then `A` is never lost - read about what assignment means

Comment: No it's not possible.

Comment: You could if using an ``xor`` but ``and`` and ``or`` operations are destructive.

Comment: In _general_: No.  Consider `B == 0`, then `A & B` --> `C == 0`.  No hope to recover `A`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't recover `A`, but you can write `A = (X & ~B) ^ C`. Here, `X` can be anything (and it gives all the `A`'s).

Of course this will work only for `B` and `C` such that `C & ~B == 0`.

This is a parametrized solution. Example in python

```
>>> A = 32776466
>>> B = 89773888
>>> C = A & B
>>> C
22020352
>>> X = 1234567890    # arbitrary value
>>> U = (X & ~B) ^ C
>>> U
1238761874
>>> U & B     # same result as A & B
22020352
```

Comment: I've been downvoted by someone who doesn't understand the beauty of this formula :(

Comment: Or who doesn't understand what it has to do with the question. There are other possibilities.

Comment: @EJP It's very simple, in general, when `C & ~B == 0`, the equation `A & B == C` with unknown `A` has several solutions. The set of all these solutions can be described as the set of `(X & ~B) ^ C` when `X` takes all possible values. Here it is assumed that `A, B, C` are not boolean but rather c-like integers and that one performs bitwise operations on these integers, but I think this is implied by the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is really helpful.

Answer (score 8):

No, it's not possible. You can see this from the truth table for AND:

```
A  B  C (A & B)

0  0  0
0  1  0
1  0  0
1  1  1
```

Suppose you know that B is 0 and C is 0. A could be either 1 or 0, so it cannot be deduced from B and C.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know the truth table of AND operator indicates the lacking of information of C. Do you think a combination of OR, XOR, NAND, ... can recover A from B and C?

Comment: No, it can't, because in the case of B and C being 0, A could be either 1 or 0, so the table indicates a lacking of information of *A*. If B is 0 then C will be 0 regardless of the value of A. Think of it another way: the AND operation is equivalent to a multiplication table for the values 0 and 1. If you know that A * 0 = 0, how can you solve for A? It's impossible.

Answer (score 5):

You can recover only bits of `A` that have `1`s in the corresponding bits of `B`. For bits of `B` that have zeros it does not matter what `A` has in the corresponding position, because the bit in `C` would be zero anyway:

```
A = 1xx0x011x0
B = 1001011101
    ----------
C = 1000001100
```

Positions of `A` marked with `x` can be zeros or ones; the information in them is going to be lost either way.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know the truth table of AND operator indicates the lacking of information of C. Do you think a combination of OR, XOR, NAND, ... can recover A from B and C?

Comment: @ThuanN. The info is gone, not hidden. You can't "recover" it, because it does not matter what was there in the `x` positions. It's like trying to recover `A` from the result of `A * 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are just talking binary logic not C variables, then no.

Consider:
    `a=0111, b=1010` therefore `c=0010`

So you have `b=1010, c=0010` so now how can you find `a`?

The left most bit in `c` is a 0, in `b` it is 1 so we know `a` it must be 0
The second bit in `c` is 0, in `b` it is 0 so you can't tell what it was in `a` (either 1 or 0 leads to a 0 in `c`)

At this point we've proven you can't do it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know the truth table of AND operator indicates the lacking of information of C. Do you think a combination of OR, XOR, NAND, ... can recover A from B and C?

Comment: As in if you had "A&B=C" and "A|B=D" could you figure out A from B C and D?.

Answer (score 2):

No, because there isn't a unique solution. Any value of A that has the same bits set as B would satisfy the equation, regardless of the other bits.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I know the truth table of AND operator indicates the lacking of information of C. Do you think a combination of OR, XOR, NAND, ... can recover A from B and C?

Comment: No I don't, for the reason I already stated: there is no unique solution. What you are asking is *a priori* impossible. You don't seem to have grasped this elementary point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question about equations.  It is not possible as the degree of freedom is not zero.  It is the same as asking a+b = 10 -- what is a and what is b?